# Why must I interval 2 days to show yesterday?

Tags: mysql, date, intervals

I am running the following query:

```
select  
    'detail' as DB,
    Store,
    count(Store)
from
    detail
where 
    date(TransactionDateTime) > subdate(curdate(),interval -1 day)
```

This returns me nothing.  If I run the same query interval -2 days I get all the results from yesterday.
When I run the following:

```
select curdate();
```

I can confirm that I have the correct date in my system.
Why am I having to interval 2 days to see yesterday? No other schema I queried has had this occur using the same mysql server.

Comment: Use  `>=` instead of `>`

Comment: That was it, feel a little silly I overlooked that.  Only letting me up vote your comment, won't let me mark as answer...

Comment: Since it was only a typo you can simply delete your question.